# Number of coin flips required to get heads for every unfair coin in a set

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have $n$ unfair coins, but each is distinctly unfair: the $i$-th coin ($1 \leq i \leq n$) has probability $p_i$ of landing on heads and $1 - p_i$ of landing on tails.

I repeatedly flip the first coin until I get heads, while taking note of how many flips were required to get heads, which I call $f_1$. I repeat this process for each of the $n$ coins, taking note of each $f_i$.

Is there a standard probability distribution for the random variable $f_T = \sum_{i = 1}^n f_i$? The closest I've found is the [Poisson binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution), but it doesn't account for the rule of flipping the coins again until they land on heads.

In particular, I'm looking for the value of $k$ such that, for a given set of parameters ($n$ and the set $P = \{ p_1, \ldots, p_n \}$) plus a probability $q$ (say 99.999%), at most $k$ flips (across all coins) will be required to get heads from each of the $n$ coins, with probability $q$. Put it another way, the probability of needing $> k$ flips is $1 - q$.

Comment: It seems like each $f_i$ is a [geometric RV](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with success probability $p_i$. (There’s two conventions for such RVs, depending on whether you only count the tails flips.) So what you’d be studying is a sum of independent geometric RVs. Since the RVs are not identically-distributed, one can’t appeal to the central limit theorem. But one can use the usual tricks with characteristic functions to hopefully get something useful.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I used the probability-generation function (PGF) from the linked Wikipedia article, and then the sum of the RVs is given by the product of the PGFs -- call it $G(x)$. Finally, one can recover the probability that $n$ heads will come up after exactly $k$ flips by computing $G^{(k)}(0)/k!$, where $^{(k)}$ indicates the $k$-th derivative. Too bad the problem appears impossible to solve numerically for not-small $n$, due to exponential growth in the polynomial degree while computing derivatives. Thus, a closed-form solution would still be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to numerically solve the problem in my range of interest of $n$ by the following procedure, inspired by probability-generating functions:

1. For each coin $i$, initialize a polynomial such that the coefficient of $x^k$ is $(1 - p)^{k - 1} p$ (i.e. the probability, in the geometric distribution, of heads coming up for the first time in the $k$-th throw), except for the constant coefficient, which is initialized to zero. I cut off the polynomial when the probability becomes “sufficiently low” (heuristically).
2. Multiply together all these polynomials.
3. Perform a prefix sum of the coefficients.

I used SageMath with `RealField` coefficients of a suitable precision. I was able to compute this for $n$ in the range of hundreds very quickly (under a minute).